# Export entire class through c++ interface

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, dll

Ok, I'll rewrite the question(s).
1. Is it enough to do

```
class __declspec(dllexport) CXyz {
public:
int Food() {printf("Food\n");}
};
```

So that the class could be used like this in the exe:

```
#include "CXyz.h"
CXyz obj;
obj.Food();
```

2. What happens when I do CXyz x ( member & methods code allocation), I mean does it allocate a linear structure with the size of (aprox. members size + function pointers for the methods) and method code is in the section .code of the program? What happens when I do CXyz *pX ?

Comment: Do you have the source code of your .exe?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Half the words you say don't mean anything: You can't "export a class". Code isn't "allocated". There is no such thing as a "pointer of a class". What's wrong with just using a header file?

Comment: This is clearly one of RTFM questions; ways to export class from DLL were discussed many times. I only wish plugin proposal will be revised and accepted for C++1x...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not enough. On the client side CXyz must be declared as __declspec(dllimport). This is usually done by conditional compilation, when some macro is expanded to __declspec(dllexport) in Dll, and to __declspec(dllimport) in a client project. Create sample Dll using VS Application Wizard, check "Export symbols" on one of the Wizard steps, and see, how it is done. And of course, client project should be linked with server .lib file, and server Dll should be available at runtime.
2. Only class members (and possibly vtable) are allocated. Class methods on Assembly level are global functions with hidden "this" parameter.