# Exporting and importing dll interface in c++ not working

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Export entire class through c++ interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455852/export-entire-class-through-c-interface)

Starting from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL#CppMatureApproach) tutorial I have atried to do my own VS solution with 2 projects  a .dll builder and an .exe builder, here is the .dll project header:
libheader.h

```
#pragma once
 
#ifdef SHREDLIB_EXPORTS
#define SHREDAPI __declspec(dllexport)
 
#else
#define SHREDAPI __declspec(dllimport)
 
#endif

struct IShred
{
    virtual int GetStringSize(char*) = 0;
    virtual void Release() = 0;
};

// Handle type. In C++ language the iterface type is used.
typedef IShred* SHREDHANDLE;

#ifdef __cplusplus
#   define EXTERN_C     extern "C"
#else
#   define EXTERN_C
#endif // __cplusplus


EXTERN_C
SHREDAPI 
SHREDHANDLE 
WINAPI 
GetShred(void);
```

the libheader.cpp

```
#include libheader.h
class IShredLib: public IShred {
    int GetStringSize(char*);
    void Release();
};

int IShredLib::GetStringSize(char* s)
{
    return strlen(s);
}
void IShredLib::Release()
{
    delete this;
}
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:GetShred=_GetShred@0")
SHREDAPI SHREDHANDLE APIENTRY
GetShred()
{
    return new IShredLib;
}
```

and this in the main.cpp exe project:

```
#include "libheader.h"
 
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IShred* itf = ::GetShred();
     
     
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Now why do I get this?
**Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetShred@0**
I have also defined the SHREDLIB_EXPORTS as a c++ preprocessor define in VS .dll project properties.

Comment: Is the DLL's import library getting linked in to the executable?

Comment: @KerrekSB there I was asking how   and here I am asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: The thing is that it doesn't get linked, cause it is a linking error, another thing the .dll and the .exe are in the same directory.

Comment: I don't think you need the `#pragma comment(linker...)` bit, since you already have the `SHREDAPI` declaration on the function.  That is enough to get the function to be exported.  Another thing you can try is depends.exe to see what names your DLL is exporting, and what names your app is expecting to import.

Comment: Having the dll and exe in the same directory can help at runtime, but your error is a build issue. You're trying to use a symbol that doesn't exist -- you need to include the .lib (or you need to manually manage your dll loading and symbol resolution at run time).

Comment: But it works in the tutorial source? what I am missing? It just includes the .h file with the #define SHREDAPI __declspec(dllimport)
and that is very cool.

Comment: Why have you added the pragma export of the mangled name? The tutorial doesn't do it. Take it out. Should return new IShredLib be IShredLib()?

Comment: The source of the tutorial does it! and even so with it taken out, it still doesn't work! Return new shred lib should return a pointer of type IShred to the new IShredLib instance( it's derived class).